# Mysql - Using temporary. Mysql создает временную таблицу при условии where

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В базе данных есть таблица районов, новостей и связующая новости с районами, так как одна новость может отображаться на нескольких районах.

Есть скрипт

```
select news.id
from `news`
inner join `news_rayon` on `news_rayon`.`news_id` = `news`.`id`
where `news`.`type` = 'news'
and `news_rayon`.`rayon_id` = 20
order by `public_date` desc
limit 25 offset 0
```

EXPLAIN показывает что для таблицы news_rayon использується 189320 rows и **Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort**.
Таблица новостей имеет больше милиона записей и соответственно news_rayon еще больше.Также таблица новостей имеет поле type которое делит их на типы news, topics, bogs.
Запрос который в примере, выполняеться 14 секунд. Если убрать условие `` news_rayon`.`rayon_id` = 20 `` тогда мгновенно. Либо когда  я указываю `USE INDEX (news_public_date_index)`, также мгновенно.
Созданы связи и проставлены индексы для столбцов.
Игрался с изменениями параметров памяти для сортировки и других настроек. Не работает. Уже незнаю куда копать

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news` (
                                  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                  `type` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
                                  `rayon_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                  `status` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 2,
                                  `public_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
                                  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                  `description` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `news_rayon` (
                                        `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                        `rayon_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                        `news_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                        `is_moder` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 1
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4   COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `rayons` (
                                    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
                                    `sub_domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                                    `region_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL ,
                                    `status` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                                    `published` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                                    `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
                                    `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
                                
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;


ALTER TABLE `news`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `news_public_date_index` (`public_date`),
ADD KEY `type` (`type`);

ALTER TABLE `news_rayon`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
ADD KEY `news_rayon_news_id_foreign` (`news_id`),
ADD KEY `news_rayon_rayon_id_foreign` (`rayon_id`);

 ALTER TABLE `rayons`
   ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   ADD UNIQUE KEY `rayons_sub_domain_unique` (`sub_domain`),
   ADD KEY `name` (`name`);


ALTER TABLE `news`
   MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `news_rayon`
   MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
ALTER TABLE `rayons`
    MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `news_rayon`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `news_rayon_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`rayon_id`)  REFERENCES `rayons` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `news_rayon_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`news_id`) REFERENCES `news` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Даные:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151378/discussion-on-question-by-hlud09-mysql-using-temporary-mysql--); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: Переходите в чат по ссылке выше, для дальнейшего обсуждения

Comment: Чтобы объединить два аккаунта посмотри справку: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts